# forcats::fct_lump_prop() behavior

Tags: r, tidyverse, factors, forcats

I have been struggling using the `{forcats}` `fct_lump_prop()` function, more specifically the use of its `w =` and `prop =` arguments. What exactly is it supposed to represent with the example below :

```
df <- tibble(var1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3)),
             var2 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  var1   var2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a       0.2
2 a       0.3
3 a       0.2
4 b       0.1
5 b       0.1
6 b       0.1
```

What would be the `prop` value to set so that `a` is kept intact, but `b` is lumped as `Others` ?

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  var1   var2  fct
  <chr> <dbl> <fct>
1 a       0.2   a
2 a       0.3   a
3 a       0.2   a
4 b       0.1   Others
5 b       0.1   Others
6 b       0.1   Others
```

I have tried empirically but can't find how this works. Intuitively I would say that setting a `prop` value above 0.3 (sum of `b`s) and below 0.6 (sum of `a`s) would lump the `b` factor but this doesn't lump anything. The only threshold I found was with `prop = 0.7` and then everything becomes a `Others` level...

```
df %>%
  mutate(fct = fct_lump_prop(var1, w = var2, prop = 0.7))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  var1   var2 fct  
  <fct> <dbl> <fct>
1 a       0.2 Other
2 a       0.3 Other
3 a       0.2 Other
4 b       0.1 Other
5 b       0.1 Other
6 b       0.1 Other
```

So what am I not understanding ? The little examples I found elsewhere did not help me grasp the `prop` and `w` behavior.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Michaël, i add a relevant edition at the answer.

Comment: Thank you Ric ! I did spot this issue on Github, but somehow I was not making the link between my example and the said behavior (not lumping one level of factor). You helped me a great deal, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant explanation is in [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/blob/2bceece43e0a599050c2347eb15677a09f2e9857/R/lump.R#L126) line of the source of `fct_lump_prop()`

```
if (prop > 0 && sum(prop_n <= prop) <= 1) {
   return(f) # No lumping needed
}
```

That is, if there are only one factor in "others" the function does nothing.

```r
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(var1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3),rep("c", 3)),
             var2 = (1:9)/(45))

df %>% group_by(var1) %>% summarise(sum(var2))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   var1  `sum(var2)`
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 a           0.133
#> 2 b           0.333
#> 3 c           0.533

df %>%
  mutate(fct = fct_lump_prop(factor(var1), w = var2, prop = 0.45))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   var1    var2 fct  
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 a     0.0222 Other
#> 2 a     0.0444 Other
#> 3 a     0.0667 Other
#> 4 b     0.0889 Other
#> 5 b     0.111  Other
#> 6 b     0.133  Other
#> 7 c     0.156  c    
#> 8 c     0.178  c    
#> 9 c     0.2    c

df %>%
  mutate(fct = fct_lump_prop(factor(var1), w = var2, prop = 0.25))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   var1    var2 fct  
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 a     0.0222 a    
#> 2 a     0.0444 a    
#> 3 a     0.0667 a    
#> 4 b     0.0889 b    
#> 5 b     0.111  b    
#> 6 b     0.133  b    
#> 7 c     0.156  c    
#> 8 c     0.178  c    
#> 9 c     0.2    c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It does'nt appear to be documented except in the source code itself.

### Edit

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues/312) in github because manpage says that factors are lumper if they appear "fewer than" prop times, but it is also true if it appears "exactly" prop times.